# Hadoop: Distinct count of a value (Java)

Tags: java, hadoop, distinct

Example of (key,value) in the mapper : (User,(logincount,commentcount))

```
public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {

            String tempString = value.toString();
            String[] stringData = tempString.split(",");

            String user = stringData[2];
            String activity = stringData[1];

            if (activity.matches("login")) {
                outCount.set(1,0);
            } 
            if (activity.matches("comment")) {
                outCount.set(0,1);
            }

            outUserID.set(userID);

            context.write(outUserID, outCount);

        }
```

I count the logins & comments of a user. Now i want to change the count: Count every login & look if the user wrote a comment.
How can i achieve that my mapper or reducer just search for one comment of the user and "ignores" all other comments (of this user)?

**Edit:**

Log-File:

```
2013-01-01T16:50:56.056+0100,login,User14133,somedata,somedata
2013-01-01T16:55:56.056+0100,login,User14133,somedata,somedata
2013-01-01T05:20:44.044+0100,comment,User14133,somedata,somedata,{text: "something here"}
2013-01-01T05:24:44.044+0100,comment,User14133,somedata,somedata,{text: "something here"}
2013-01-01T20:50:13.013+0100,login,User76892,somedata,somedata
```

Output at the moment:

```
User14133   Logins: 2   Comments: 2
User76892   Logins: 1   Comments: 0
```

Input:

```
Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, UserCount>
Reducer<Text, UserCount, Text, UserCount>

public static class UserCount implements Writable {
        public UserCountTuple() {
            set(new IntWritable(0), new IntWritable(0));
        }
```

My mapreduce counts every login and every comment of a user and sum them up.
What i want to achieve is something like this ->
Output:

```
User14133   Logins: 2      Comments: 0 or 1 (Did User wrote one comment?)*

 * In Mapper or Reducer (?)
 for every line in the log{
   if (user wrote comment){
     return 1;
     ignore all other comments from same user in this log;
   } else if (user didn't write anything) return 0;
 }
```

Comment: What are your output key and output value types? And if you could provide a set of input values and the kind of output values you expect, then maybe we can help you better.

Comment: what do you mean by 'Count every login' ? Also as asked above, if you can just provide sample input and corresponding sample output it would be great...

Comment: I edited my Question, i hope now you understand what i mean :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you just want to get the total number of unique users who logged in, along with the total number of comments?

I recommend using the "aggregate" reducer in Hadoop.

In your mapper, output lines that look like this:

```
UniqValueCount:unique_users      User14133
LongValueSum:comments            1
UniqValueCount:unique_users      User14133
LongValueSum:comments            1
UniqValueCount:unique_users      User14133
LongValueSum:comments            1
UniqValueCount:unique_users      User14133
LongValueSum:comments            1
UniqValueCount:unique_users      User76892
LongValueSum:comments            1
```

And then run the "aggregate" reducer on this, you should get an output that looks like:

```
unique_users    2
comments        5
```

I'm assuming this is what you want?

Comment: My final idea is to get the number of unique users, who logged in and then compare how many of those user did wrote a comment. Something like: Total Logins of Unique User: 234 Total Comments: 20.